# Add Shapefile loader plugin to PgAdminPortable

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgadmin, postgis, plugins

I'm using PgAdminPortable and I'd like to enable « PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader » plugin. The issue is that the files are not structured as in a PostgreSQL complete install (see below).

[image]

I have tried the following steps:

1. Add the lines below (see end of post) into `D:\PgAdminPortable\App\PgAdmin\plugins.d\pugins.ini` file. The plugin appears now correctly inside the plugins dropdown within pgAdmin, but when clicking it, I'm asked several DLLs files.
2. Create a `postgisgui` folder within `D:\PgAdminPortable\App\PgAdmin`.
3. Copy - paste missing DLLs files from a local PostgreSQL install into `D:\PgAdminPortable\App\PgAdmin`(I have no `bin` directory within PgAdminPortable folder). There are about 10 files missing. Once copied, I get a new error message saying that the program could not start...

---

```
;
;PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui (Windows):
;
Title=PostGIS Shapefile and DBF loader
Command="$$PGBINDIR\postgisgui\shp2pgsql-gui.exe" -h "$$HOSTNAME" -p $$PORT -U "$$USERNAME" -d "$$DATABASE" -W "$$PASSWORD"
Description=Open a PostGIS ESRI Shapefile or Plain dbf loader console to the current database.
KeyFile=$$PGBINDIR\postgisgui\shp2pgsql-gui.exe
Platform=windows
ServerType=postgresql
Database=Yes
SetPassword=Yes
```